# Why is there no XML-File with metadata when I download Landsat 8 data on USGS?

Tags: usgs, open-data-cube

I am trying to create a Data Cube with Open Data Cube for my Bachelor's Thesis. In the Python-Files from Open Data Cube to prepare the data for indexing there is a XML-File with metadata needed:
https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-dataset-config/blob/master/agdcv2-ingest/prepare_scripts/landsat_collection/usgs_ls_ard_prepare.py

But when I download Landsat 8 data from USGS there is only a txt-File with metadata and no xml-File. Where do I get this xml-File?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the XML as a separated file if you use Landsat ARD (if you wonder why I mentioned ARD it's because of the file name `usgs_ls_ard_prepare.py`). ARD only covers the conterminous United States (CONUS), Alaska and Hawaii only (from https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/us-landsat-analysis-ready-data?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con)
You can get at least the file from [Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov) in the "Download Options" when you search "US Landsat 4-8 ARD", look at one image "Download Options" and you find the XML in the "Metadata (114.0 KB)" button in below screenshot.

[image]

For other Landsat data sources, the XML is not provided as they use firstly what they call MTL file format (a text based file describing metadata associated with the data)